# Need to "rip" part of this string and place it in a variable, how?

Tags: php, html, regex, cookies

I create a string and place it inside a cookie like this:

```
$cookie_value = $salt1.':'.$username.':'.sha1($row['alt_username']);
//THEN INSERT INTO COOKIE
```

Then I fetch the cookie data like this:

```
$data = $_COOKIE['cookie_name'];
```

I need to take out the $username out of the data in the cookie. How can I do so?

As you can see, the username is surrounded by colons.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example value of $cookie_value.

Comment: I don't have a standard example value. As you see, the sha1 and salt could be anything I believe. Atleast I think so. I can however, change the pattern if you would like it so, but it must remain secure!

Comment: If the salt is really anything then you'll have a serious problem when it contains ":".

Comment: isnt the salt supposed to be some sort of secret, and sending it out there kind of defeats the purpose.. either that, or i am about have a crisis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
list($salt, $username, $hash) = explode(':', $data);
```

You can also drop the `$salt` and `$hash` if not needed and simplify it to this:

```
list(,$username) = explode(':', $data);
```

Comment: Could a SHA1 include colon as well? Then that would mess this all up.

Comment: SHA1's contain only letters and numbers, and it wouldn't even matter if it did contain colons as it comes after the username. On the other hand, if `$salt` contains a colon, then you're out of luck.

Comment: He'll need to escape the colon while concatenating and take this into consideration in the regex or explode.

Answer (score 0):

SHA1 generates fixed size message digests of 160 bits. Using that information you can strip off the hash from the end and then find the username quite easily (assuming it doesn't contain any colons).